# Nexus Docker-Registry behind NGINX returns 502 on docker login

Tags: docker, nginx, nexus

My admin and I are frustrated because we can't figure out how to set up the docker-registry part of nexus correctly.

We've setup the "docker-hosted"-Repository in Nexus.
Below you can find the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen   *:443;
    server_name  server.local;
 
    # allow large uploads of files
    client_max_body_size 50G;
 
    # optimize downloading files larger than 1G
    #proxy_max_temp_file_size 2G;
 
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      snakeoil.crt
    ssl_certificate_key  snakeoil.key
 
    location / {
      # Use IPv4 upstream address instead of DNS name to avoid attempts by nginx to use IPv6 DNS lookup
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
   
    location /v1/ {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
       proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

When hitting login we only get:

```
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://someToplevelURL.com/v2/ failed with status: 502 Bad Gateway
```

Another thing is, why is it forcing us to `/v2` even if we toggle the "Use v1" button in nexus?

Comment: did you clear your cache? Or even go to network tab and right click one of the redirect and say clear history or cache or something like that? With nginx is common that when you play around with your config, you will sooner or later look at a "stale" configuration rather than what you just did.

Comment: The toglle button in nexus GUI does not force to use v1 but "Allow(s) clients to use the V1 API to interact with this repository". In other words a client using v1 will not be denied, but it's up to the client to decide. Yours is apparently using v2... which is reverved proxied to port 8081 and not to your docker registry on port 5000